# C++ rw/rwdate.h library no such file or directory

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a c++ program which will compute a date in `YYYYMMDD` format.
The program takes a date and a number and return a computed date.

> e.g 20190101 - 2 will return 20181230

The program imports `rw/rwdate.h` library.
I hit below error when i use gcc to compile the program.
My gcc version: `gcc version 4.8.2 (GCC)`

> fatal error: rw/rwdate.h: No such file or directory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <rw/rwdate.h>
#include <rw/rstream.h>

main (int argc, char **argv)
{
char year[5];
char month[3];
char day[3];
char newDate[9];    /* YYYYMMDD */

strncpy(year, argv[1], 4);
strncpy(month, &argv[1][4], 2); 
strncpy(day, &argv[1][6], 2); 
year[4] = 0x00;
month[2] = 0x00;
day[2] = 0x00;

RWDate d = RWDate(atoi(day), atoi(month), atoi(year)); 

RWDate y;
if (argv[2][0] == '+')
   y = d.operator+= ( atoi(argv[3]) );
else
   y = d.operator-= ( atoi(argv[3]) );

/* output to outFileName */
ofstream oFile;
oFile.open(argv[4], ios::out);
oFile << newDate << endl;
oFile.close(); 

char newDateM[7];    /* YYYYMM */
char fileM[80];

sprintf(newDateM, "%04d%02d", y.year(), y.month());
sprintf(fileM, "%sM", argv[4]);

oFile.open(fileM, ios::out);
oFile << newDateM << endl;
oFile.close();
```

}

Comment: Well the first question is did you write `rw/rwdate.h` and `rw/rstream.h` yourself? If not what makes you think they should be available to you? They aren't standard header files.

Comment: OK, answering my own question I can see that those header files belong to the very ancient Rogue Wave library. So that's the next question, do you think you have Rogue Wave installed on your system?